# new db import, mysql_insert_id() returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I have this short script in the admin side of a site that will either upload and image or upload a link to the database. I've recently moved the site from a hostpapa server to a godaddy server. This script worked great on hostpapa. After import to the godaddy server only uploading images work. Uploading a link fails and the id returns 0. Its odd because the auto_increment is set and uploading images proves that the auto_increment works just fine. Not sure why the id returns 0 for link uploads and nothing gets inserted into the db when I try to upload a link.

```
include '../connect.php';

if ($_POST['upload'])
{
//get file attributes.
$name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$type = $_POST['type'];


if ($name)
{
 $location = "imgs/$name";
 $dir = "../imgs/$name";
 move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$dir);

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `links` VALUES ('','$title','','$location','$type')");
//last id
$id = mysql_insert_id();
    echo $id,$location,$title;
 die ("Image successfully uploaded.");

}

//this bit below is what doesn't work as it should.
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `links` VALUES ('','$title','$url','','$type')");
//last id
$id = mysql_insert_id();
    echo $id,$url,$title;
 die ("Link successfully loaded.");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ed Cottrell and his suggestion to use:

```
echo mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error();
```

I was able to see that the error was in not using - mysql_real_escape_string because the error sprung was a syntax error which was because the title of the link contained an apostrophe.

Implementing the  mysql_real_escape_string in the variables solved the problem. Thanks Ed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost certainly with [`magic quotes`](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8383/what-is-magic-quotes). GoDaddy enables magic quotes by default, which could easily be breaking your queries, especially since you only wrap the data in `'` and don't do any escaping of the input. Try turning off magic quotes by putting this at the top of your script, and the problem should go away.

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function magicQuotes_awStripslashes(&$value, $key) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    $gpc = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    array_walk_recursive($gpc, 'magicQuotes_awStripslashes');
}
```

Also, you should know that `mysql_*` is deprecated and unsafe -- you should use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Finally, you are wide open to SQL injection. You said this is an admin area of the site, but you can't assume nothing bad will ever make it to this page. Use prepared statements or at least `mysql_real_escape_string()` on each variable used in your queries.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Once I get this working again I will implement. for now turning off magic quotes had no effect. :( problem persists.

Comment: Please put `echo mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error();` right before your call to `mysql_insert_id()`, then let us know the error you see when you try to save a link.

Comment: Also, please post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; hard to see what's happening without it.